# Update record from LWC on force.com website

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

Can we update a record from the Site Guest User, I have a LWC wherein I am using record-edit form to update a record. Do we have some attributes like we have ignoreEditPermissionForRendering in VF page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but not to update a record, rather to post to Chatter as site guest user and I did a workaround, where I made a POST request to my own Salesforce org by using a named credentials and auth. providers.

I authorized the Auth provider as System admin user so everytime the site guest user made a POST request using named credential, it worked as a system admin. You can do something like that to update a record?